# How spring replace the method invocation which has a return type already registered as a Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

for example, in

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<byte[], ABCPayload> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
    Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
    props.put(
            GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
            String.format(KAFKA_GROUP_ID, KAFKA_CLIENT, ClientId.getHostname(), UUID.randomUUID()));
    props.put(MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "3600000");
    props.put(REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "300000");
    props.put(SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<byte[], ABCPayload>
kafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<byte[], ABCPayload> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(**consumerFactory(kafkaProperties)**);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setBatchErrorHandler(new BatchLoggingErrorHandler());
    factory.setConcurrency(CONCURRENT_CONSUMERS);
    return factory;
}
```

Even though the `consumerFactory(kafkaProperties)` is called, however, it never really get executed again.
Instead it would just return the same Bean as already registered.

I know this is how Spring handles Singleton. However, just would like to figure out the inside, how Spring does that.